# Unable to get data from ajax function and wcf rest service on Firefox and Chrome but works fine with IE

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wcf, google-chrome

I am calling ajax function which return some data in JSON format from wcf rest service. I am getting data when I user IE browser but it's failed to get data when I use Mozilla and Chrome browser.

Following is the code I am using.

```
    <script src="js/JSon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 function fillcategory() {
                var GetCategoryURl = "http://localhost:4444/Service1.svc/GetCategory"
                var drp = "";
                   $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        type: "GET",
                        async: false,  
                        url: GetCategoryURl,
                        dataType: "json",   
                        success: function (objCategory) {
                            Category = objCategory;                               
                        }
                    ,
                        error: function (xhr) {

                        }
                    });

                 fillSubcategory();
            }
```

Rquest Header is:

```
    OPTIONS /Service1.svc/GetCategory?_=1350649411289 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4444
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.28) Gecko/20120306 Firefox/3.6.28
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/json
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:14853
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
```

Response Header is:

```
    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 19 Oct 2012 12:23:56 GMT
```

Comment: What is the error you get or does it simply fail silently?

Comment: It's just fail silently xhr status text is empty.

Comment: Clean you cleanup your indentation a little? It's somewhat hard to follow. Also if you open Firebug/developer tools can you see that the HTTP GET is sent?

Comment: Btw. the code works just fine with me: http://jsfiddle.net/MEXnN/2/

Comment: I have added Response and Request header in my post. May be that will be helpful to diagonse issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in your global.asax file for your sever side code(services) it works sure,

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall();

    }

    private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```